# how to code the boundary of the contour plot

Tags: c++, plot, contour, boundary

I am thinking how to write the code to describe the boundary of  the contour plot. My procedure is below:

I have a contour plot of S (x axis) and T (y axis) from the experiments. Theoretically, S is a function of two other parameters (m,n), the same as T. I want to use the contour plot of S and T to constrain the parameters m,n.

I am doing a scan of parameter space m,n, then for the m, n satisfying the S and T are within the contour, then I keep m, n, otherwise I pass it. But I do not know how to code the boundary, does anyone have any ideas?

[image: S vs T contour]

Answer (score 0):

You can try conrec algorithm from Paul Bourke. It's implemented in many languages and also good explained. It uses the marching cube algorithm. It's also explained how to use it with functions.

Comment: Thank you very much. Would you offer some more details?